# Repeat Excel Spreadsheet for 100 pages

Tags: excel

I am currently working with a spreadsheet that I am going to need to have 100 identical pages, each numbered accordingly 1-100. Is there a way in Excel to repeat a spreadsheet an arbitrary number of times? Currently, my only solution is to copy/paste the contents of the page 100 times. I would like to avoid that if possible, as there are situations where I may need 50, 100, or 200 pages printed. Of course, I could just copy/paste it 200 times, and then just print the necessary pages, but that would be a file that is 200 times larger than necessary, and not as easy to work with.

Comment: How do you number? By inserting Page Number?

Comment: I imagine either by having a page footer, or some other way. I suppose that is part of the question as well. Not sure how the pages would be numbered if the spreadsheet itself is only one page..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subroutine:

Sub PrintPage(pageNumber As Integer)
   ActiveSheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "Page " & pageNumber
   ActiveSheet.PrintOut
End Sub

Comment: Can I do this directly within Excel, or would I need to have a separate program that actually prints the spreadsheet?

Comment: Alright, thanks. I don't think I will be able to use macros in this instance, as the file is going to be sent to a printing company to be mass produced. I will check with them and see if they allow macros.